# Why is function-less slower?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7

I've built a code to compute the largest prime factor of a number:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()

num = 600851475143
while num % 2 == 0:
    num /= 2
if num == 1:
    i = 2
else:
    i = 3
    while num > 1:
        if num % i == 0:
            num /= i
        else:
            i += 2
print "%s \n --- %s seconds ---" % (i, time.time() - start_time)
```

It runs in 0.000769853591919 seconds. 
Searching online I've found a similar but faster [solution](http://code.jasonbhill.com/python/project-euler-problem-3/). I applied the idea to my code and this is the result:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()

def lpf(num):
    while num % 2 == 0:
        num /= 2
    if num == 1:
        return 2
    else:
        i = 3
        while num > 1:
            if num % i == 0:
                num /= i
            else:
                i += 2
        return i        

l = lpf(600851475143)

print "%s \n --- %s seconds ---" % (l, time.time() - start_time)
```

It runs in 0.000453948974609 seconds.
It's almost twice as fast as the previous one. I do not understand the logic: the code is identical, but yet the longest code runs faster. Why is it?

Comment: Have you used something like `timeit` to get a better handle on actual performance? You're way down in the level of random noise running it once like that, and `time.time()` isn't exactly the most precise timing method.

Comment: To get a better feel for the time difference, if any, run each version in a loop through a large range of numbers rather than once with a single number. Also -- no version which relies on trial division will be particularly fast, though that is another issue.

Comment: Need more data points. The computer could have been processing something else at the time. Get a large average over, say, 30 seconds each, and then compare the two numbers.

Comment: Ok, I'm looking at 'timeit' library right now,  and I will try to run each version in a loop through a large range of numbers. But I've tried timing both codes more than once and I've always got the same results: first one is almost 0.0008 seconds and second one is about 0.00045 seconds.

Comment: BTW, this may or may not matter to CPython, but an implementation using a more tightly constrained variable scope can be more aggressively optimized, since code can't need to have side effects visible to other threads if all its variables are local.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's do a better job of testing, running 10,000 iterations of each, and excluding the function definition time from the latter (to count only runtime):

```
>>> import timeit
>>> c1='''
... num = 600851475143
... while num % 2 == 0:
...     num /= 2
... if num == 1:
...     i = 2
... else:
...     i = 3
...     while num > 1:
...         if num % i == 0:
...             num /= i
...         else:
...             i += 2
... '''
>>> timeit.timeit(c1, number=10000)
3.5007779598236084
```

...and the alternative:

```
>>> c2_setup='''
... def lpf(num):
...     while num % 2 == 0:
...         num /= 2
...     if num == 1:
...         return 2
...     else:
...         i = 3
...         while num > 1:
...             if num % i == 0:
...                 num /= i
...             else:
...                 i += 2
...         return i
... '''
>>> c2_run='l = lpf(600851475143)'
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=c2_setup, stmt=c2_run, number=10000)
3.3825008869171143
```

...a **far** smaller difference.

---

So, why any difference at all? To put it in language-agnostic terms, it's easier to optimize away changes to local variables; they don't need to be written to a scope where they're accessible by any other threads of execution which may or may not be running. In a JITted compiler (like PyPi or the JVM), changes to locals may actually end up being implemented as register modifications that don't go to off-CPU memory at all.

CPython doesn't have JIT support, but @chepner gave us our answer there: Reads from global variables use a more expensive `LOAD_GLOBAL` instruction, vs the `LOAD_FAST` available for locals.

Comment: And that could be explained by the difference between `LOAD_GLOBAL` vs `LOAD_FAST` for the variable lookups.

Comment: I see, but still, the problem remains: why the function-version is faster? Shouldn't it be slower?

Comment: @Pigna, why would you expect it to be slower? It's easier to optimize: It can't have side effects to things that don't share its stack. Faster makes more sense.

Comment: ...whenever a change happens to a module-scoped variable, that change needs to be visible to anything else accessing the module.

Comment: *grumbles about how back in his day compiler design was mandatory coursework*.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't know, "the longer it is, the longer it takes to run" kind of logic? I'm a beginner... :/ I don't really get it

Comment: I am an autodidact, not a CS student. Could you give me a link related to this, so that I can understand?

Comment: You might start with https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Local_Variables

Comment: ...that said, I'd strongly suggest eventually learning assembly language, and how modern compilers, function calls, &c work at an instruction level. Having a mental model that includes registers, stacks, &c will do you a lot of good, even if your work is in high-level languages; see http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html if you want a good read.

Comment: The number of characters in a program has very little to do with computer program speeds. The study of algorithm run time is a field in itself. The study of optimizing how an operating system runs a program is a body of science of similar if not greater scope. Trying to explain a tiny time difference between two very similar programs' run times running on a modern general-purpose computer's operating system would be a very difficult task.

Comment: ...indeed; many of the places where glibc (GNU libc) is slower from embedded libc implementations such as uclibc or diet libc are places where it trades against size and complexity for better algorithmic performance. Although code size itself can become a performance issue -- a slightly slower algorithm that can fit in L1 cache is going to work much better than a slightly faster one that can't.